# Store data without a database?

Tags: php, database, store

If I would like to store emails, but don't have a database (e.g. MySQL), what should I do?

The data should be accessible and writable from PHP, but regular "visitors" MUST NOT see the data.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Please clarify your question, where are these emails coming from, are you trying to attach to a mail server, are you just storing text from user input, have you tried anything already.

Comment: if you don't have a database, then you should get one

Comment: if no database then why u want to add ?

Comment: It's user submitted email addresses i would like to store, so i can contact them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data not very large, you can use XML files.
But if your data is important and you must secure it , you have to encrypt your data

Answer (score 9):

You can put them in files :)

```
$data; // Defined "somewhere"
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $data);
```

However, I suggest you to use a database anyway. At least SQLite is installed nearly everywere.

Comment: Well, the problem is the file would be public accessible.

Comment: @Mikkel: Only, when YOU put it somewhere, where it is public accessible ;) Just dont save it below the document-root (or in any other public/shared folder).

Comment: @Mikkel not necessarily, the file can be put in a folder not accessible to the public

Comment: @Mikkel: If you are _really_ not able to install (or let install) a database-server and also dont have access to any private directory, you should consider leaving your hoster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function mail($to, $subject, $body) to send the email address to your personal email.  The data will not be readable from your script, but for your use case this might be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Look, while I really don't suggest this, in a pinch you can always output it to a .php file with the first line being exit().

So be sure, you can always */ $mail */ to the file, but this is a poor substitute for the security of having a database to store the information.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what Outlook does: create your own file format for the mail and dump mails inside. And implement your own reader.(Its re-inventing the wheel sometimes). But its going to award you with a tonne of control over your mails, allowing for easy back up when needed.