# CakePHP custom login (no DB)

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I made a form for admin login which is in `login.ctp`:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Admin', array('action' => __('login'))); 
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label' => __('Uporabniško ime',true)));
echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label' => __('Geslo',true)));
echo $this->Form->submit('Login');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

I also have `index.ctp` which is what will be shown when admin logs in. What I would like to do when the user presses *Login* button is to manually try to validate the user (right now by comparing to a string). I've created a login function in AdminController.php - however, when I click on Login button on my form I get redireted to /admins/login instead of /admin/login which generates error  *AdminsController could not be found.* Why do I get redirected on wrong page?

Comment: Type error? Admin `s` Controller or just wrong in code. That might then explain why it doesn't work

Comment: In code I never used `admins` but I just found out that in *Form->create* whatever you put in as first argument will get an aditional `s` at the end. How to disable it?

Comment: Maybe there is something going on with `plural` words. You might check that.

Comment: Correct, I've read that, but that way I am unable to use /admin - I need to use /admins which looks bad.

Comment: `/admin` is defined by the name of your controller. Not by plurality of labels. I'm not experienced with CakePHP, but multiple frameworks just translate the labels to plural by adding an `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
 echo $this->Form->create('Admin',array('url'=>array('controller' => 'Admin', 'action' =>  "login")));
 ?>
```

Comment: This works, the problem is I need to have users stored in DB therefore having a model. Is it possible to login without any model (using only session)?

Comment: So you have not created a model for your user table?

Comment: Check this http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Primordial/2012/01/19/cakephp_v2_without_a_database_fixed

Comment: No, I DONT WANT ANY DB! :)

Comment: The link I sent in previous comment details how to use Cakephp without a database. You simply have to set $useTable=false in your model.      If it is not helpful, can you please explain you requirement a bit more.

Comment: Ok, I am having a database, but not for users/admins. I want to check for admin credentials in a NOOBS way, i.e. comparing two strings (for simplicity's sake). So the problem is that CakePHP forces me to use models and stuff although I have no table in DB containing any credentials. How can I make a simple login without looking up for credentials in DB hence not using any model?

Comment: Ok. You can store your data in file using file_put_contents('filename.txt', $data);    and to verify whether the admin credentials are correct, you can retrieve the data from the file and compare.  This may help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095520/store-data-without-a-database) . It is better if you store details in XML file.                You can get the needed help from this link: (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?14165-Read-and-write-XML-with-PHP)

Answer (score 1):

If you want quick log-in for only single account, I have created a simple plugin for this case. You are up and running in only few minutes!

https://github.com/CanesCZ/SimpleAuth

Usually one site admin is enough. If you have any problems, let me know!